# Is it possible from iPhone application to connect with server if app is not running?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, currentlocation

Actually I have the following scenario:

I want to create an app that will check the user's current location and send Apple push notifications based on the user's current location.

I know it is possible when the app is running, but I want to know, is this possible when the app is not running? Is there any way my app can send the user's current location to my web server so that it can send relevant push notifications?

Comment: You should rephrase your question towards: `is it possible for an iPhone app to connect with a server when running in background`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Go to your `info.plist` and add a new line with the key of Required Background Modes. Open up the array that was just created and for Item 0 set the value for the key to "App registers for location updates".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to register as a location-based application. See [Getting the User’s Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) in the Location Awareness Programming Guide, and [Tracking the User’s Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) in the iOS App Programming Guide.